Context Length Limitation When Fine-Tuning Llama 3.1 in Colab
I am fine-tuning the Llama 3.1 model in Google Colab Pro using an A100 GPU with a custom dataset (using LoRA techniques) via the Unsloth library. Below is the LoRA code I am using:
max_seq_length = 2048
model = FastLanguageModel.get_peft_model(
    model,
    r=16,  # Choose any number > 0 ! Suggested 8, 16, 32, 64, 128
    target_modules=["q_proj", "k_proj", "v_proj", "o_proj",
                    "gate_proj", "up_proj", "down_proj"],
    lora_alpha=16,
    lora_dropout=0,  # Supports any, but = 0 is optimized
    bias="none",     # Supports any, but = "none" is optimized
     
    use_gradient_checkpointing="unsloth",  # True or "unsloth" for very long context
    random_state=3407,
    use_rslora=False,  # We support rank stabilized LoRA
    loftq_config=None,  # And LoftQ
)
from trl import SFTTrainer
from transformers import TrainingArguments
from unsloth import is_bfloat16_supported
trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    train_dataset=dataset,
    dataset_text_field="text",
    max_seq_length=max_seq_length,
    dataset_num_proc=2,
    packing=False,  # Can make training 5x faster for short sequences.
    args=TrainingArguments(
        per_device_train_batch_size=2,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
        warmup_steps=5,
        # num_train_epochs = 1, # Set this for 1 full training run.
        max_steps=60,
        learning_rate=2e-4,
        fp16=not is_bfloat16_supported(),
        bf16=is_bfloat16_supported(),
        logging_steps=1,
        optim="adamw_8bit",
        weight_decay=0.01,
        lr_scheduler_type="linear",
        seed=3407,
        output_dir="outputs",
    ),
)

When loading the model, we must specify a maximum sequence length, which restricts its context window. Llama 3.1 supports up to 128k context length, but I am setting it to 2048 in this example since it consumes more compute and VRAM. Additionally, the dtype parameter automatically detects if your GPU supports the BF16 format for more stability during training (this feature is restricted to Ampere and more recent GPUs).
My Questions:

If I set max_seq_length to 2048 while training, what will be my model's context length after training, 128k or 2048?
After training the model, can we utilize a context length of 128k, or will it still be limited to 2048?

